# Python:- Given a list of tuple coordinates, find the nearest coord to a specified coord (Google Maps Coords))

Tags: python, google-maps, distance

I'm Using Python and done something with the following, Given a list of tuple coordinates, find the nearest coord to a specified coord (Google Maps Coords)).

But not accurate nearest coordinates compared with google maps on my code. Please help me.

Here is my code

```
def find_coords(c, l):
    tmp_list = []
    (x,y) = l[0]
    for (a,b) in l[1:]:
            if (x-c[0])**2 + (y-c[1])**2 > (a-c[0])**2 + (b-c[1])**2:
                    (x,y) = (a,b)
                    tmp_list.append((x,y))                  
    return tmp_list 

ccoordinate_list = [(11.6702634, 72.313323), (11.6723698, 78.114523), (31.67342698, 78.465323), (12.6702634, 72.313323), (12.67342698, 75.465323)]

coordinate = (11.6723698, 78.114523)

while coordinate_list[1:]:      
     coordinate_list = find_coords(coordinate, coordinate_list)
```

Comment: It's great that you've posted some code, but you _could_ have added it to your earlier question (edited questions get bumped to the front page).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find the nearest geo coord you should use specific geo-coordinate structures (please see [geopy](https://github.com/geopy/geopy) ). In this case, I propose the following solution:

```
import geopy
import geopy.distance
# your data    
ccoordinate_list = [(11.6702634, 72.313323), (11.6723698, 78.114523), (31.67342698, 78.465323), (12.6702634, 72.313323), (12.67342698, 75.465323)]
coordinate = (11.6723698, 78.114523)
# the solution
pts = [ geopy.Point(p[0],p[1]) for p in ccoordinate_list ]
onept = geopy.Point(coordinate[0],coordinate[1])
alldist = [ (p,geopy.distance.distance(p, onept).km) for p in pts ]
nearest_point = min(alldist, key=lambda x: (x[1]))[0] # or you can sort in by distance with sorted function
```

Please note that Euclidean metric (as in your example) may be incorrect on the globe.

Comment: Interesting! It's nice that geopy provides both great-circle & Vincenty distance, with Vincenty being the default.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your results differ from Google's is that you are using the distance formula for the plane (Pythagoras' Theorem), but the Earth is not a flat plane, and latitude & longitude are not a [Cartesian coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system).

That flat formula is ok for small distances in regions that are not too close to the poles. For much better results you can use the [great circle distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) formula.

For even more accuracy, you need to account for the fact that the Earth is not a perfect sphere: it is somewhat flattened at the poles, making it an ellipsoid (almost). To calculate distances on an ellipsoid you can use [Vincenty's formulae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae). Even those formulae aren't perfectly accurate, but the error is quite small.

**Update**

Vincenty's formulae are not recommended for modern use. They date from the 1970s, and were intended for use on the desk calculators of the time. We now have access to much better computing technology, and there are better ways to calculate distances on the ellipsoid. I recommend C. F. F. Karney's [`geographiclib`](https://pypi.org/project/geographiclib/). Dr Karney is a major contributor to the Wikipedia articles on geodesics, in particular [Geodesics on an ellipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_on_an_ellipsoid), as I mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40803546/4014959) which has a brief demo of using `geographiclib` to compute the distance between 2 points on the WGS84 reference ellipsoid, as well as a link to a more extensive example.