# Minimum of itertools.product in python

Tags: python, python-itertools

```
import itertools

A = [50, 60, 70]
B = [0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.4]

print [a + b for a, b in itertools.product(A, B)]

>> [50.3,50.1,50.5,50.4,60.3,60.1,60.5,60.4,70.3,70.1,70.5,70.4]
```

In the above code, is there a way to just return the minimum value of a + b for each a? so the output should be:

```
[50.1,60.1,70.1]
```

please note this is a toy example, in the real example A and B are lists of lat and lon values and I compute the great circle distance between them

Comment: So why not just use `min_b = min(B)` then `[a + min_b for a in A]`? Why do N * M steps when N + M steps will suffice?

Comment: this is a toy example, in the real example A and B are lat and lon values and I compute the great circle distance between them. updated question

Comment: What is `great circle distance`?

Comment: great circle distance is the distance between any two points on a globe like earth. here's an example: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119846/calculating-distance-between-latitude-and-longitude-by-using-python. you could assume simple euclidean distance as well.

Comment: FWIW, if you want more accuracy than the great circle distance formula, take a look at [Vincenty's formulae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae), which treat the Earth as an ellipsoid rather than a sphere. It's quite a bit more complicated than Great Circle, so you may not want to use Vincenty unless you _really_ need it. :)

Comment: thanks! i am using a library called geopy and it has vincenty...

Comment: Ah! As mentioned in my comment to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28368926/4014959) geopy provides both great-circle & Vincenty distance, with Vincenty being the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`itertools.product` isn't really appropriate for your Great Circle task because it lumps all the (A, B) pairs into one container, but you want to keep all the pairs with a given A value together in a sub-container so you can find their minimum. So just use a pair of nested loops. If you want, you can do it as a generator expression to calculate the minimum value nested inside a list comprehension, like this:

```
A = [50, 60, 70]
B = [0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.4]

f = lambda x, y: x + y

print [min(f(a,b) for b in B) for a in A]
```

Comment: thanks! is itertools.product inappropriate because it is difficult to specify a lambda?

Comment: @user308827: It's inappropriate because it lumps all the (A, B) pairs into one container, but you want to keep all the pairs with a given A value together in a sub-container so you can find their minimum.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, first select the minimum of B, then add it to every element of A.

```
b = min(B)
print([a + b for a in A])
```

Comment: as per my comment above, this is a toy example, in the real example A and B are lat and lon values and I compute the great circle distance between them. updated question –

Comment: what if `A` has values in range [0, 1]