# Geod ValueError : undefined inverse geodesic

Tags: python, geospatial, pyproj

I want to compute the distance between two lon / lat points by using `Geod` class from `pyproj` library.

```py
from pyproj import Geod

g = Geod(ellps='WGS84')
lonlat1 = 10.65583081724002, -7.313341167341917
lonlat2 = 10.655830383300781, -7.313340663909912

_, _, dist = g.inv(lonlat1[0], lonlat1[1], lonlat2[0], lonlat2[1])
```

I get the following error :

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-8ba490aa5fcc> in <module>()
----> 1 _, _, dist = g.inv(lonlat1[0], lonlat1[1], lonlat2[0], lonlat2[1])

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyproj/__init__.pyc in inv(self, lons1, lats1, lons2, lats2, radians)
    558         ind, disfloat, dislist, distuple = _copytobuffer(lats2)
    559         # call geod_inv function. inputs modified in place.
--> 560         _Geod._inv(self, inx, iny, inz, ind, radians=radians)
    561         # if inputs were lists, tuples or floats, convert back.
    562         outx = _convertback(xisfloat,xislist,xistuple,inx)

_geod.pyx in _geod.Geod._inv (_geod.c:1883)()

ValueError: undefined inverse geodesic (may be an antipodal point)
```

Where does this error message come from ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those two points are only a few centimetres apart. It looks like `pyproj` / `Geod` doesn't cope well with points which are that close together. That's a bit strange, since simple plane geometry is more than adequate at such distances. Also, that error message is a bit suspicious, since it's suggesting that the two points are [antipodal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antipodal_point), i.e., diametrically opposite, which is clearly not the case! OTOH, maybe the antipodal point it mentions is some intermediate point that arises somehow in the calculation... Still, I'd be rather hesitant in using a library that behaves like this.

Given this defect, I suspect that `pyproj` has other flaws. In particular, it probably uses the old [Vincenty's formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty's_formulae) for its ellipsoid geodesic calculations, which is known to be unstable when dealing with near-antipodal points, and not particularly accurate over large distances. I recommend using the modern algorithms of C. F. F. Karney.

Dr Karney is a major contributor to the Wikipedia articles on geodesics, in particular [Geodesics on an ellipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_on_an_ellipsoid), and his [geographiclib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geographiclib/1.46.3) is available on PyPi, so you can easily install it using `pip`. See his [SourceForge site](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net) for further information, and geographiclib binding in other languages.

FWIW, here's a short demo of using geographiclib to compute the distance in your question.

```
from geographiclib.geodesic import Geodesic

Geo = Geodesic.WGS84

lat1, lon1 = -7.313341167341917, 10.65583081724002
lat2, lon2 = -7.313340663909912, 10.655830383300781

d = Geo.Inverse(lat1, lon1,  lat2, lon2)
print(d['s12'])
```

**output**

```
0.07345528623159624
```

That figure is in metres, so those two points are a little over 73mm apart.

---

If you'd like to see geographiclib being used to solve a complex geodesic problem, please see this [math.stackexchange answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1340899/207316) I wrote last year, with Python 2 / 3 source code on [gist](https://gist.github.com/PM2Ring/c78f492392560d7bc2c21479eb140d60).

---

Hopefully, this is no longer an issue, since [pyproj now uses code from geographiclib](https://github.com/jswhit/pyproj/blob/master/Changelog).

Comment: [It seems like pyproj now uses geographic lib to do calculations.](https://github.com/jswhit/pyproj/blob/master/Changelog).

Comment: @mnky9800n Thanks for that info!

Comment: Note that this package is also [available for Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/geographiclib): `> conda install -c conda-forge geographiclib`